# list of images that put together in a line

Tags: android, android-listview, android-xml

I want to put some images in a line and when the line fill out goes to other line.
my list view put every image in a different line.i put the images with an adapter.
here is my list view:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        />
```

and my images:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what's stopping you to do that?

Comment: You can use a GridView for that and increase or decrease the spacing between them accordingly. Check this out: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's imposible with ListView. GridView would be the best choise for such task. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: should i change the list view or add grid view in image view?

Comment: Yes, you should replace ListView with GridView.